# Nothing happening when creating symlink

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, symlink

I've had a good look about but not been able to find out what's going on when I'm trying to create a symlink for a new site in Nginx it's pretty simple what I'm doing:

```
ls -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

But all i'm getting is:

```
4 /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/:
total 4
0 default  4 myothersite.com
```

In sites enabled I'm only getting a symlink to "myothersite.com" not quite sure what I'm doing wrong as I thought it was pretty simple.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Have you "service nginx reload" ?

Comment: `ls` is a typo. You really meant to type `ln`.

Comment: @edwinksl - thanks I'm feeling pretty stupid right now :) - I'd be staring at it for ages and hadn't even noticed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@edwinksl spotted the typo, ls to ln

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com
```

then

Remove the default in sites-enabled.

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Restart

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: The sudo systemctl restart nginx is not needed.